# Groovy Enum fails

Tags: groovy, enums

I have declared a simple enum in Groovy which is perfectly valid in Java. I get an error,

Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: AdmixtureProperties(String, Integer, LinkedHashMap)

Here is the enum

```
 @ToString
   enum AdmixtureProperties {
     SVALUE(prop:"1", num: 1),
     PVALUE(prop:"5", num: 3);
     private String prop
     private int num
     AdmixtureProperties(String prop, int num){
      this.prop=prop
      this.num=num
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it because you're trying to use named parameters? I thought ctors/methods taking named params should have a `Map` as the parameter, but that may have changed.

Comment: I do it with a single named parameter and works with no issues. It's not only complaining about a map, its looking for string, integer and map which i find baffling. It's using more than 1 parameter where it fails with an error.

Comment: Did you try it without the named parameters, or with a `Map` parameter in the ctor def?

Comment: That's not "perfectly valid in Java"  as Dave says, try it without the named parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have declared a simple enum in Groovy which is perfectly valid in Java.

This would not be a valid enum in Java for a couple of reasons

- Missing semicolons at the end of statements
- Unsupported constructor invocation syntax `SVALUE(prop:"1", num: 1)`

To make this valid Groovy code, fix the constructor invocations, i.e. replace this:

```
SVALUE(prop:"1", num: 1),
PVALUE(prop:"5", num: 3);
```

with

```
SVALUE("1", 1)
PVALUE("5", 3)
```

Comment: I agree with this answer and as a comment, you have to choose: you either a) use named params and remove the constructor in your code or b) don't use named params and use the constructor as in this answer. So either named params + no constructor or no named params + constructor (unless you want to write a constructor which takes a map which I personally find not that readable).